# Timeout Mongo BD com AspNetCore hospedado no servidor smarterasp

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

Tenho uma web api em Asp Net Core realizando leitura numa base não relacional no Mongo DB.

Rodando a aplicação localmente com a conexão apontada para o servidor Atlas Mongo DB funciona perfeitamente, mas ao subir a aplicação para o servidor https://www.smarterasp.net/, é apresentado erro de timeout:

" A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }......"

A versão do servidor Asp Net Core é **ASP.NET 2.x, Integrated**.

A connection string recomendada pelo Mongo DB Atlas é para a versão **C# .NET 2.11 ou superior.**

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando não é possível realizar a conexão dentro de 30 segundos. O mais comum é que seja um erro de configuração. Verifique se o seu servidor tem conectividade com o atlas (firewall em ambos os lados), bem como as configurações de endereço, usuário e senha que estão na app publicada para o servidor, pois algum procedimento de publicação poderá ter alterado.

Answer (score 0):

Após entrar em contato com a equipe de suporte do https://www.smarterasp.net/, fui informado que para realizar a conexão com qualquer outro servidor de banco de dados é necessário assinar um pacote mensal.

Obrigado a todos que de alguma forma, tentaram me ajudar.